# Launch meteor with a shell script

Tags: macos, shell, meteor, automator

I have no trouble starting my meteor server from the terminal window.  But surely I can do this from a shell script that I make with Automator.  This is what I do in the terminal window:

```
cd myAppName
meteor
```

For the the automator shell script, I change the directory differently:

```
cd /Users/myName/myAppName
```

... and that seems to work fine.  But the next line gives a "meteor --command not found" message.  I read somewhere that the shell that automator runs doesn't have access to the Environment variables that the terminal window uses.  That must be the problem.  So how do I run meteor from the shell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the PATH variable from inside your script. It should include the directory path to your meteor executable.

It should be something like:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/meteor/bin/meteor
```

After that meteor should launch. If meteor starts launching but it fails then you're missing more environment variables inside your script and you must export them as you did with the PATH.

To know which environment variables you have in your shell type this:

```
set
```

Comment: Initially this didn't work, but used the 'set' command as you advised and found this line: PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin   so I replaced the path value in that export command with this path value and bingo!  Works like a charm.  Thanks.